# Negating folders with Gulp and then including a singular file from same directory

Tags: gulp

I'm using Gulp and I have a folder that has several `.js` files in in, of which I only need one of them; I read up on negating files within Gulp and from what I understood you should *remove* them first and then afterwards you can add them back in case you didn't want to negate them all.

I have this code for example:

```
var js_scripts = [
    'js/dev/lib/**/*.js',
    'js/dev/plugins/**/*.js',
    '!js/dev/plugins/fancybox/*.js',
    'js/dev/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js',
    '!js/dev/plugins/inner/*.js',
    '!js/dev/plugins/jquery.bxslider/**/*.js',
    'js/dev/plugins/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js',
    // We have to set the bootstrap lines separately as some need to go before others
    'js/dev/bootstrap/collapse.js',
    'js/dev/bootstrap/dropdown.js',
    'js/dev/bootstrap/tab.js',
    'js/dev/bootstrap/transition.js',
    'js/dev/scripts.js'
];

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(js_scripts)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', ['scripts'], function() {
    return gulp.src(js_scripts)
        .pipe(gulpif('!**/*.min.js', uglify({mangle: false})))
        .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});
```

However I have just noticed that both `js/dev/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js` and `js/dev/plugins/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js` have not been included in the output files even though I added them back in after initial removal.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options) it states that:

> Note that globs are evaluated in order, which means this is possible:

```
// exclude every JS file that starts with a b except bad.js
gulp.src(['*.js', '!b*.js', 'bad.js'])
```

So the fact that I first *include* the whole `plugins` directory and then remove everything inside `js/dev/plugins/jquery.bxslider/` and *then* re-add the file `js/dev/plugins/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js` for example then should should include that file?

I noticed if I removed this line: `!js/dev/plugins/jquery.bxslider/**/*.js` then it gets included.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There are a few questions here about the order of evaluation of globs not working as expected when negation is involved.  See particularly https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/837#issuecomment-68069722 which I have referenced before.  Can you switch to gulp4.0 and see if it works as expected - or https://github.com/UltCombo/gulp-src-ordered-globs.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-add-src would also work for you.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for that. Is 4 a beta version? `3.9.1` shows as the latest version on npm. As for `gulp-add-src`; thanks - good to have another option.

Comment: gulp4 might still be in beta but has been for some years!!  Quite a few people are using it so ….  It does have gulp.series and gulp.parallel built-in so that is nice.

Comment: @mark Got it working with v4 :)